# Youtube video's wont start

Tags: firefox, windows-10

I am having this problem from a long time , and it is really annoying

I have a windows 10 64bit machine ,with mozilla firefox for win 64 latest version
I have 3 addons `Idm integration` and `Tamper data` and `Adblock plus`

It happend to me when I had windows 7 too , Basically what happen is when I open any video it get stuck like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5O7u.jpg) for the whole day, it happen with all the video's and won't go until few hours or when I restart the browser

When I try it on different browser it works perfectly

Comment: Does this happen if you launch Mozilla with a clean user profile?  The way you can determine this is to, archive the current Firefox user profile, then delete it and launch Firefox.

Comment: Yes, the same result

Comment: Does it work as expected if you disable/remove the mentioned add-ons?

Comment: Removing the addons do not change anything, I am not an expert but I think it is a problem of firefox managing dns, It is like if firefox requested google.com but because my connection was slow in that moment, The request took too long, So anytime I request google.com after that Firefox will automaticly will hang forever loading google.com

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - He already did that by using a clean profile.  Which is the reason I asked that.

Comment: @jokoliptos - If you suspect DNS problems provide us the required information to confirm if your route to youtube.com is slow or not.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may need to set *NoScript* to allow particular third-party scripts. Test this by right-clicking on the screen, select *NoScript* in the context menu, and *Temporarily allow all this page*.
2. Try using HTML5 rather than Adobe *Flash* playback. The [YouTube Flash Video Player](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-video-player/) extension makes selection of either mode easy.
3. Since you believe that DNS lookup might be an issue, in *about:config*, find "network.dns.disablePrefetch" and double-click it to toggle it to *True*. See [Mozilla's page on fixing such an issue](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can).
4. You may need to mouse- over the video toolbar and click the red button.
   [image]